# Check for files and then do a followup?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to check if a folder is empty or has a file in it with a batch command.

I already have this code (which works): `>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "folderName\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No file found)`

Now I want to start an .exe if there are files in that folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method using the **Where** command:

```bat
Where/Q C:\Users\Gunter\FolderName:*
If %ErrorLevel%==0 Start "" SomeFile.exe
```